# Cannot output a XSLT variable including "<"

Tags: html, xslt

Following XSLT code works:

```
<xsl:variable name="ret"> RET </xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="$ret" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

It outputs "RET". But this code does not work as expected:

```
<xsl:variable name="ret"> <RET/> </xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="$ret" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

I expect the output to be `<RET/>`.

I am doing this for the purpose of capturing output of "xsl:apply-templates" into a variable. The output of "xsl:apply-templates" may include HTML tags (e.g. blah,blah). I hope I can store the output into a variable and do some processing afterworlds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xsl:value-of` instruction creates **a text node**. It does so by converting the selection to a string. Your variable contains an empty element that has no string-value - and converting it to a string results in an empty string.

To pass the variable contents to the output tree with no conversion, use the `xsl:copy-of` instruction.

---

P.S. In your original question you wrote:

> I expect the output to be `"<RET/>"`.

which indicates you thought the variable contains the **string** `"<RET/>"` that can be used to create an element by copying it to the output without escaping it. But in order to create such variable you would have to use:

```
<xsl:variable name="ret">&lt;RET></xsl:variable>
```

And in any case, that's not a good way to create output.

Answer (score 0):

Use xsl:copy-of instead of xsl:value-of.